# Why does the order of the elements returned from a REST method differ between Postman and Lambda?

Tags: c#, json, rest, xml-serialization, postman

When I call a REST method from Postman, the data is returned with the elements in this order:

[image]

IOW:

```
VendorId
VendorItemID
Id
PackSize
```

When I call the REST method from a client app, though:

```
private IEnumerable<VendorItem> GetCollectionOfVendorItems()
{
    ArrayList arrList = 
FetchDataFromServer("http://localhost:21608/api/vendoritem/getall");
    String contents = "<VendorItems>";
    foreach (String s in arrList)
    {
        contents += s;
    }
    contents += "</VendorItems>";
    String unwantedPreamble = "<ArrayOfVendorItem xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CStore.DomainModels.HHS\">";
    contents = contents.Replace(unwantedPreamble, String.Empty);
    contents = contents.Replace("</ArrayOfVendorItem>", String.Empty);
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(contents);
    IEnumerable<VendorItem> vendorItems = xmlDoc.Descendants("VendorItem").Select(x => 
GetVendorItemForXMLElement(x));
    return vendorItems;
}

private static VendorItem GetVendorItemForXMLElement(XElement vendor)
{
    return new VendorItem
    {
        Id = vendor.Element("Id").Value,
        PackSize = Convert.ToInt32(vendor.Element("PackSize").Value),
        VendorId = vendor.Element("VendorId").Value,
        VendorItemID = vendor.Element("VendorItemID").Value
        //VendorId = vendor.Element("VendorId").Value,
        //VendorItemID = vendor.Element("VendorItemID").Value,
        //Id = vendor.Element("Id").Value,
        //PackSize = Convert.ToInt32(vendor.Element("PackSize").Value)
    };
}

public class VendorItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int PackSize { get; set; }
    public string VendorId { get; set; }
    public string VendorItemID { get; set; }
    public String siteNum { get; set; }

    //public string VendorId { get; set; }
    //public string VendorItemID { get; set; }
    //public string Id { get; set; }
    //public int PackSize { get; set; }
    //public String siteNum { get; set; }
}
```

...it returns the elements in this order:

[image]

(You've heard of Big Data, that's Wavy Gravy data)

IOW:

```
Id
PackSize
VendorId
VendorItemID
```

Even with the order of members in the class matching the return from Postman, it makes not difference; either way, I get Id first, etc.

Why would that be? It doesn't seem to matter, but am I wrong?

c# REST postman xml json

Comment: Different codes behaves differently.

Comment: Both ways of getting the data call the same REST method, which returns (one would think, anyway), the same data in the same manner, regardless of who calls it (how would it even know)?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Yes, but one return json and another returns xml. At the very least, they are using different serialization code. FWIW, I have ServiceStack code that does the same thing. xml comes in alphabetical order, but json in another order probably whatever order reflection returns the properties in.